# How do I change the resource folder for a few ASP.Net controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webusercontrol

I am using ASP.Net localization and the default local resource folders... but... it would be nice to be able to maintain a second set of alternative resource files in certain circumstances. In that case, it would be nice if the controls worked like this:

```
 SomeControl.ResourceFolder = "~/CustomResources/"
```

Or

```
 SomeControl.SetResourceFolder("~/CustomResources/");
```

That way, I could point to a new resource folder in some situations.

Does anyone know how to implement this type of functionality as an extension method?

Comment: I think I'm looking at this issue the wrong way. I was thinking more functional and abstract, but I think the resource files are conversions of a set from one locale to another where the transformation of resource A will always be converted to resource B. So the better approach would be to load the local resource file with alternatives Key, Key_1, Key_2, then use something like GetLocalResourceObject() to pick among the alternatives.

Comment: For example the values "Sign-In", "Log in", and "Login" would all be in one resource file with the keys: SignIn, SignIn_2, SignIn_3.

Comment: In addition, if a color change when along with the SignIn resource key, then that could be an additional SignIn_4, SignIn_5 resource keys to show the differences.